# using body parser to pass zip file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I've node app which use express, in the app I need to send via post message **zip file** (e.g. from postman to the node server) ,currently I use body parser like following but I wonder if this is OK?

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.text({
    type: 'application/text-enriched',
    limit: '10mb'
}));
```

Btw this is working but I wonder if I use it right...

Comment: Are you expecting to receive or send a zip file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bodyParse.text()` is meant for `string` type body. From the documentation:

> **bodyParser.text(options)**
>
> Returns middleware that parses all bodies as a string...

Since, you are uploading binary data (e.g. zip file), using `bodyParser.text()` will [convert your buffer body to `utf-8` string](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/master/lib/types/text.js#L77). So you'll lose some data for binary files and the zip file could be unreadable.

For binary file, use [`bodyParser.raw()`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserrawoptions), which will give you a buffer in `req.body` and you can safely save that buffer in a file.

```
app.use(bodyParser.raw({
    type: 'application/octet-stream',
    limit: '10mb'
}));
```

For file uploads, you should really look at [`multer`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer), which works for `multipart/form-data` content-type.